# Stuck on dplyr - merge in R

Tags: r

New to R, and this is my second question in two days. I want to merge two data frames by subregion for a county map. There are plenty of examples and documentation on how to do this, which i perused, but my code still won't fly. Anyway , here's what I have.

```
library(dplyr)

#Examine data set/s

#Data frame: County polygon points
> head(oc_df)
           # long      lat group order region subregion
# 59960 -83.66902 39.02989  2012 59960   ohio     adams
# 59961 -83.56590 39.02989  2012 59961   ohio     adams
# 59962 -83.37109 39.06426  2012 59962   ohio     adams
# 59963 -83.30806 39.06426  2012 59963   ohio     adams
# 59964 -83.30233 39.05280  2012 59964   ohio     adams
# 59965 -83.25649 39.01842  2012 59965   ohio     adams

#Data frame: Indemnity 
head(oi_df)

# subregion indemnity
# 1 adams                           42778.25
# 2 allen                           88580.26
# 3 ashland                        167509.27
# 4 ashtabula                       25738.28
# 5 athens                           7080.00
# 6 auglaize                        99353.25


#Make sure indemnity is numeric & county is character
oi_df$indemnity <- as.numeric(oi_df$indemnity)
oi_df$subregion <- as.character(oi_df$subregion)

#Attach every point on polygons of the counties
ohcopa <- inner_join(oc_df, oi_df, by = "subregion")

#I get a list  of 0 obs. and 7 variables. 

#When that didn't work  I tried
ohcopa <- merge(oc_df, oi_df, by = "subregion")

#Still the same
```

Probably missing something basic, not sure what it is.

```
str(oi_df)
'data.frame':   86 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ subregion: chr  "adams                         " "allen                         " "ashland                       " "ashtabula                     " ...
 $ indemnity: num  42778 88580 167509 25738 7080 ...

> str(oc_df)
'data.frame':   1427 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ long     : num  -83.7 -83.6 -83.4 -83.3 -83.3 ...
 $ lat      : num  39 39 39.1 39.1 39.1 ...
 $ group    : num  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ order    : int  59960 59961 59962 59963 59964 59965 59966 59967 59968 59969 ...
 $ region   : chr  "ohio" "ohio" "ohio" "ohio" ...
 $ subregion: chr  "adams" "adams" "adams" "adams" ...
```

Comment: Can you post the outcome of `str(oi_df)` and `str(oc_df)`?

Comment: @coffeinjunky see post below. Is there a way to edit the original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
oi_df$subregion <- trimws(oi_df$subregion)
```

Try to merge afterwards.

If you look at the your subregion as defined in `oi_df`, you see e.g.

```
 "adams                         "
```

Note that there are quite many white spaces in that name. However, from your second dataframe, we get

```
 "adams"
```

with no white space whatsoever.

Hence, the keys you are merging on are different, and need to be adjusted first. That is, the whitespace from the first key needs to be removed (or added to the second one, but let's just not think about that one). The function `trimws` in the base package or e.g. `str_trim` in `stringr` (and many other equivalent functions in other packages) does this for you.

Comment: It worked! perfect! I had no idea this function even existed. Damn trailing whitespace :/

Comment: Yep, I think we have all been there. Easy thing to miss if you are not aware of it.